# jQuery change link href with .load()

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to make a dropbox-like custom context menu. What I need is that when the user right-clicks an element, the options such as "Edit" and "Delete" that pop up in the context menu *link to "edit" and "delete" for that specific element*. The context menu:

```
<div class="screenlock-transparent">
<div class="context-menu-wrapper">
    <ul class="context-menu">
        <a href="<?php echo $edit_url; ?>"><li><i class="icon-edit" style="margin-right: 10px;"></i>Edit</li></a>
        <a href="<?php echo $delete_url; ?>"><li><i class="icon-trash" style="margin-right: 10px;"></i>Delete</li></a>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

The way I have gone about this is to user jQuery to fire an event when the user right-clicks an element:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Launch on-right-click on element
    $(".custom-context-menu").mousedown(function(){
        if(event.which == 3) {
            if ($(this).hasClass("ul-all-years-faculty")) { // If on the general faculty ul
                // Load external php here to build url string specific to the element
                // Replace current href value with the url string produced by the external php script
            } else if ($(this).hasClass("ul-year-specific-faculty")) {
            } else if ($(this).hasClass("ul-semester")) {
            } else if ($(this).hasClass("ul-subject")) {
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Where you see the quotes if the if statement is where I am trying to write the code that will call my external php script and replace the href of the, for example, "Edit" link in the context menu with an href of a url containing variables specific to the element that was right-clicked.

I know how to use .load() for a div - $("#ID").load(...) will load in the echoed content inside that div. However, what about loading inside the href of a link (a) ?

Thank you so much. I greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, and you want to change the href of an a tag, you want to use the .attr() function

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

so it would look something like this

```
$("a").attr("href", "http://newlink.com")
```